# Line Integral with Vector Plot Parametric Plot and Show

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, vector-calculus

How can I make different plottings of this line integral where $C$ is the square bounded by lines $x = \pm 1$ and $y = \pm 1$.

$$
    \begin{equation}
    \int_C 4y^3dx-2x^2dy
    \end{equation}
    $$

I want to use $\texttt{VectorPlot[ ], ParametricPlot[ ]}$ and $\texttt{Show[ ]}$ to create a visualization of $C$ over the vector field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a guess, but I will take a shot at what you want.  I am guessing that your vector field is

```
F = {4 y^3, -2 x^2}
```

and with

```
dr = {dx, dy}
```

then

```
F.dr
(*4 dx y^3 - 2 dy x^2*)
```

gives you the integrand of your line integral.

You can plot with

```
p = VectorPlot[F, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}];

c = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thick], Transparent, Rectangle[{-1, -1}, {1, 1}]}]

Show[p, c]
```

[image]

I am not sure what you plan to do with `ParametricPlot`, but this plot shows your vector field and the path of your line integral.

Answer (score 1):

You have specified a scalar.  (What vector are you referring to?)

```
Plot3D[4 y^3 - 2 x^2, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

[image]